# Dart using Json_object to produce strong typing

Tags: dart

Using the ideas outlined in ding the article  *Using Dart with JSON Web Services* at https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/, I have been trying to implement the section on using JsonObject and interfaces to produce a strong typing of JSON data.

The article indicates that one should write something like.

```dart
abstract class Language {
  String language;
  List targets;
  Map website;
}

class LanguageImpl extends JsonObject implements Language {
  LanguageImpl(); 

  factory LanguageImpl.fromJsonString(string) {
    return new JsonObject.fromJsonString(string, new LanguageImpl());
  }
}
```

However the compiler 'fail' at the definition of the class LanguageImpl with the message

> Missing inherited members: 'Language.website', 'Language.targets' and
>   'Language.language'

Even more confusing the code will run without a problem....

Comment: You need to add the @proxy annotation to the LanguageImpl class, it's not inherited from JsonObject unfortunately. Gory details [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6111).

Answer (score 0):

In Darteditor you get Quick fix support for this.
Set the caret at LanguageImpl and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or use the context menu > Quick fix.
You get the missing concrete implementations you inherit from the abstract base class generated automatically.

Dart is a dynamic language and therefor very flexible.
The tools support you and try to give meaningful warnings and hints about what could go wrong
but don't prevent you running a program even when it is not yet finished.

You can use [the @proxy annotation](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core.html#proxy) on the class to silent the warnings.
This also needs the class to have a `noSuchMethod()` implementation.

Comment: thanks, but the concrete class should not implement the properties defined in the interface class as they will be 'implemented' by the JsonObject at run time via the method 'noSuchMethod'. I guess there should be an annotation to inhibit the compiler error message at that line....

Comment: I extended my answer.